# Focusing a div based on the last active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which contains an iframe( which in-turn has some anchor elements ) and an anchor tag ( close button ). While navigating using keyboard, the div should be focused if 'close' button is the last active element.

But for me the focus always goes to the iframe which is inside the div. I wanted the focus on the div.

```
<a href="javascript:" class="clicker">click to open</a>

<div id="wOverlay" style="height: 307px; width: 645px; display: none;">
<span style="position:absolute;left:-1500px;top:0;width:1;height:1;overflow:hidden;">Beginning of dialog content</span>
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com" title="Quick Look - Opens a simulated dialog">
</iframe>
<a id="overlayClose" class="MultiBoxClose" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
```

Script:

```
$('.clicker').bind('click',function(){


     $('#wOverlay').attr('tabIndex',-1);
     $('#wOverlay').show().focus();

});

$(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
e = e || window.event;

if(e.keyCode == 9) {
    if($(document.activeElement).hasClass('MultiBoxClose')){

                    $('#wOverlay').focus();

    }
}
});
```

Please provide any solution

Comment: sample link : http://jsfiddle.net/JBJ9P/

Comment: Forgive me, but how does one "place the focus on a `div`"? `div`'s can't receive the focus, can they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divs by default cannot receive focus, only form elements and links.  However, in recent browsers you may be able to assign it focus by explicitly setting its tabindex.

Check this out http://api.jquery.com/focus/